# since expo 34.0.0 update fonts doesn´t load anymore, do you know how can I fix it?

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I have expo 30 proyect and the fonts ( fontello icons ) load succesful now 3 months later I reopen the proyect before update expo and fonts does´t load even if I create a new proyect the fonts does´t 
(I have already changed the import from
`import { Font } from 'expo';`
to 
`import * as Font from 'expo-font';)`
here's a snack with the problem https://snack.expo.io/@emmalv/bold-banana

it's curious that in expo-cli when I run the same code and print the state of loading first return false and before true and inmediately show red screen saying that font has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

I've tried wirtting everything in the app class instead of loading the fonts from another file and the behavior is the same

other thing I've tried is like the new documentation says, use expoAssetId

```
const expoAssetId = require("assets/fonts/custom-icon-font.ttf");
const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig, 'FontName', expoAssetId);
```

but I get another error

```
C.replace is not a function. (In 'C.replace(/\.(otf|ttf)$/,'')', 'C.replace' is undefined)
```

Expected Behavior 
the icons load and show correctly
Actual behavior 
when load throw an exception 'fontFamily "../assets/fonts/sowaicons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.' and show a square instead of the icon

**Enviroment**

- Windows 10
- sdkVersion: 35.0.0,
- expo: ^35.0.0",
- expo-font: ~7.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created working  example:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/custom-fonts

change CustomIcon code:

```
import { createIconSetFromFontello } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import fontelloConfig from '../assets/fonts/config.json';
// const ttf = require("../assets/fonts/sowaicons.ttf");
// import myfont from "../assets/fonts/sowaicons.ttf";
const Icon = createIconSetFromFontello(fontelloConfig, 'sowaicons');
```

and replace this.state.setState... to this.setState

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. Not sure why official documentation could not be written like that.