# React Native importing fonts with async componentDidMount() expected =>

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I am trying to import a font for a title of a project, and I am loading the font as such:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font'


const Home = () => {

return(
this.state = {
    fontLoaded: false
  }
   async componentDidMount(){
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'Pacifico': require('../assets/pacifico/Pacifico.ttf'),
      }).then(() => {
      this.setState({fontLoaded: true})
    })

<View style={{marginTop:30, alignItems:'center'}}>
    {this.state.fontLoaded ? (<Text>Loading...</Text>): (
    <Text style={{fontSize:40, fontFamily:'Pacifico'}}>Book Lover</Text>
    )}
    </View>
)}
```

however when I am compiling the project I get an error saying 
`Unexpected token, expected "=>"` and it points to the `async componentDidMount(){` line

is there anything I can fix?

Comment: Please look at expo snack examle in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368279/since-expo-34-0-0-update-fonts-doesn%c2%b4t-load-anymore-do-you-know-how-can-i-fix-i/58372727#58372727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Functional Component with hooks, try like this:

add to imports:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

and

```
const Home = () => {

  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(async() => {
   await Font.loadAsync({
       Pacifico: require('../assets/pacifico/Pacifico.ttf'),
    });
    setFontLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 30, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {!fontLoaded ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, fontFamily: 'Pacifico' }}>Book Lover</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```